# Where can I find release notes/changelog for ubuntu AWS AMIs - Release 20190816?

Tags: amazon-web-services, release, amazon-ami, changelog, release-notes

I use this site to locate latest release AMI for ec2.

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/

Recently, I have updated my AMI from 20190514 release to 20190816. I have tomcat server in the instance. Observed that catalina logs are showing folllowing error :-

```
2019-09-06 10:11:07,219 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Unable to write to stream
 UDP:localhost:514 for appender SYSLOGappender: 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException:
 Error flushing stream UDP:localhost:514
2019-09-06 10:11:07,224 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR An exception occurred
 processing Appender SYSLOGappender
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error
 flushing stream UDP:localhost:514
```

Where can I find what just changed between 20190514 and 20190816 release?